# Play Framework Java 2.3.8 - JSon

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.3

> Im trying to get a JSon Object from a Mock.
>   When i compile i got this error :

```
error: package org.json does not exist
In C:\workspace\tutorial\app\controllers\Application.java:18
15import models.Device;   
16import models.Task;
17
18import org(.)json.JSONArray; --> ERROR 
19import org.json.JSONException;
20
21import play.data.Form;
22import play.db.ebean.Model;
23import play.mvc.Controller;
```

This is my code:

```
public static Result index() throws JSONException, IOException {
    JSONArray json = readJsonFromUrl("http://htejera.ukelelestudio.com/mock/dmamock/devices/android");
    return ok(index.render(json.toString()));
}


private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}


public static JSONArray readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException,
        JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        String jsonText = readAll(rd);
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonText);
        return json;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

I have added libraryDependencies += "org.json" % "json" % "20140107" to the plugins.sbt

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Play's JSON library?

Comment: It does not compile neither with the Play's Json library. --> 20080701

Comment: Agree with @soong, Play incorporates Codehaus' Jackson library for JSON by default and it satisfies all the needs.

Comment: I got the same error thats why i tried to move on to a newer version in my build.